# Вывод нескольких значений из пользовательского ввода Scanner

Tags: java, консоль, scanner

Всем привет! Есть ли возможность получить из единовременного пользовательского ввода несколько значений? Например, пользователь вводит в консоль три числа подряд и нужно присвоить их разным переменным a, b, c. Получится ли это как нибудь сделать или пользователь должен каждый раз отдельно вводить новое число?

```
public class newClass {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a, b, c;
    System.out.println("Введите числа");
    // здесь должен быть нужный код
    System.out.println("первое число: "+a);
    System.out.println("второе число: "+b);
    System.out.println("третье число: "+c);
}
```

Comment: можно использовать `split` на строке. потом всё распихать по переменным...но сомневаюсь что это удобно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно спокойно сделать с помощью `scanner.nextInt()`;

Пример:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System. in );
        int a, b, c;
        System.out.println("Введите числа");
        a = scanner.nextInt();
        b = scanner.nextInt();
        c = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("первое число: " + a);
        System.out.println("второе число: " + b);
        System.out.println("третье число: " + c);
    }
}
```

Comment: А что если нам неизвестно сколько чисел введет пользователь? Как можно из полученного ввода присвоить значения переменным?

Comment: Тогда необходимо использовать while (scanner.hasNextInt()) и считывать полученные инты.

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно считывать строку, которая содержит все три числа (разделенные пробелом) и доставать числа из строки.
2. После каждого введенного числа, нажимать **Enter** и тогда нужно 3 считывания в 3 отдельные переменные.